# Running gnuplot from Fortran program under Windows

Tags: windows, fortran, gnuplot

I need to make a Fortran program(.exe) that analyses data and builds a plot.
I've decided to do this by calling gnuplot from my Fortran program along with a gnuplot settings file.
When I do this from Windows Command Line:

```
wgnuplot -persist input.txt
```

it works fine. But when I call it from Fortran program like this:

```
h=SYSTEM("wgnuplot -persist input.txt")
```

that doesn't open gnuplot.
At the same point, if I simly write:

```
h=SYSTEM("wgnuplot")
```

it successfully opens gnuplot (but, obviously doesn't draw a plot)

How can I call a gnuplot with a gnuplot settings file from the Fortran program?
I've tried to specify the whole path to the files, that doesn't help.
Also I need "-persist" key to be there, because running a command without it in CMD:

```
wgnuplot input.txt
```

does not work for me.
I've also tried all that with EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE command, and also tried to do this with C++ code like this:

```
int main(){
char command[100];
strcpy( command, "wgnuplot -persist 'gp.txt'" );
//  strcpy( command, "wgnuplot" ); // but this one works alright!
system(command);
return(0);
}
```

But I still get the same result - I can't run gnuplot with an argument file.
What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Comment: full paths for everything? wgnuplot AND input.txt? Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, for both of them. I've also added path to gnuplot into Path environment variable.

Comment: try `wgnuplot -persist -e test `  ( or in quotes `'test'` )

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have windows, so I can't test, but I suspect that it doesn't notice that everything after the space are parameters and no longer part of the program. You could try to use `EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE`, if your compiler supports it, and see whether that makes a difference. (And whether your compiler supports it in the first place.)

Comment: try `/NOEND` .... sorry i dont have windows to try this either

Comment: @chw21    call execute_command_line ("wgnuplot ")    still opens a gnuplot, but it doesn't work if I also pass arguments with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out, that the problem was with the input.txt file itself.
So actually this command works perfectly on Windows:

```
h=SYSTEM("wgnuplot -persist input.txt")
```

@shellter, @agentp, @chw21 Thank you for your help!